# Constructibility of the $\sqrt[n+1]{2} + \sqrt[n+3]{2}$ where $n$ is even

Tags: number-theory, geometric-construction

Let $n$ be even. Are there any constructible numbers of the form $\sqrt[n+1]{2} + \sqrt[n+3]{2}$?

**Attempt**

My initial hunch is no. Because the $\sqrt[n+1]{2}$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)=x^{n+1}-2$ and applying Eiseinstein's criterion with $p=2$, $f$ is irreducible thus the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[n+1]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $\sqrt[n+1]{2}$ is algebraic of degree $n+1$ which is odd since $n$ is even. Thus, $n+1 \neq 2^k$. Hence is not constructible. By similar argument, $\sqrt[n+3]{2}$ is not constructible. So does this imply $\sqrt[n+1]{2} + \sqrt[n+3]{2}$ is not constructible? If no, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is not constructible then neither is $-\alpha$ but $\alpha - \alpha =0$, so that argument does not work. Can you instead find $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n+1]{2}, \sqrt[n+3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]$ based on your observations? Can the degree of $\sqrt[n+1]{2}+\sqrt[n+3]{2}$ be even?

Comment: How about this? $Q(\sqrt[n+1]{2} + \sqrt[n+3]{2})=Q(\sqrt[n+1]{2},\sqrt[n+3]{2})$ by primitive element theorem. Consider the extension $Q\in Q(\sqrt[n+1]{2})$. So by what I have said, $[Q(\sqrt[n+1]{2}):Q] = n+1$ and  $[Q(\sqrt[n+3]{2}):Q] = n+3$. I claim $\gcd(n+1, n+3) = 1.$. Suppose $d$ was the greatest common divisor, $d \mid n+1$ and $d \mid n+3$. So $d \mid 2$. This means $d=1$ or $2$. The latter is impossible since $n$ is even. So $\gcd = 1$. This means $[Q(\sqrt[n+1]{2}, \sqrt[n+3]{2}) : Q] = (n+1)(n+3) = n^2+4n+3 \neq 2^k$ (odd).